# D3 Select <g> Element and Modify Fill

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have used D3 to make a map of the US and filled in the colors

```
var map = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
                           .attr("width", svgWidth)
                           .attr("height", svgHeight);

d3.json("us.json", function (error, us) {
    map.append("g")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .style("stroke", function (d) { return "#000000"; } )
        .style("fill", function (d) { return gradient(Math.random()); } )
};
```

Now, I want to change the color of each state but rather than removing the map and then re-adding it, I would like to transition the colors.

I have tried:

```
d3.selectAll("#map").selectAll("g").selectAll("path")
```

But then trying to loop through the elements of this array does not help.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The code I am using to try and change the colors of each state (each path variable) is...

```
d3.select(this).transition().style("fill", gradient(Math.random()));
```

I do not believe the problem has to do with the code above - it's the code I am trying to use to select the paths/states that is giving me trouble.

I have also tried

```
d3.selectAll("path").attr("fill", function (d) { ... });
```

But, that too, did not do anything. :(

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to change the colours please?

Comment: Just added some things...
Hopefully that is what you wanted!

Comment: If you've used `.style()` before you need to use it again, e.g. `d3.selectAll("path").style("fill", function (d) { ... });`.

Comment: So simple. T_T
Thanks. Probably would have never caught that.

Answer (score 0):

As Lars said in the comments, since I used "`style`" before, I have to do it again [instead of using `attr` as I was before].

Selecting the data as I did `(d3.selectAll("path"))` is the correct way to select the states.